# Keras/Tensorflow Model Works with Validation Images but Not Real World Data

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I have a model with very validation high accuracy (> 99%) that fails when run against images that are not in the original training or validation set, namely photos taken with my smartphone.

I've always felt that to learn any new technology one has to suffer with it.  To that end (and after reading and watching a bunch of machine learning tutorials) I created and labeled around 25,000 images and fed them into my CNN (mostly cribbed from the CIFAR-10 examples).

The images (buildings on my block in NY) were harvested from video taken with both a GoPro and my Android phone.  Each frame was converted to a full-sized (original resolution) jpeg file.

The images were labeled and organized into a directory structure where each sub-directory corresponded to the address (label) of the image (100MainSt, 102MainSt, etc).  This is to allow seamless integration with the Keras 'flow_from_directory' functionality.  Note that a given directory/label contains both Android and GoPro images.

The data was then divided (80/20) into training and validation data using the `sklearn` `train_test_split` function.

I ran my model with the Adam optimizer, the loss function was `categorical_crossentropy`, the learning rate was 1e-6, and each image was shrunk to 300x300 (due to memory limitations on my GPU).  After 70+ epochs my validation accuracy was 99.2% and my loss was 0.0383.  Not bad (or so I thought).

**Now my problem**: When I take photos with my phone (stills, not frames from a video as above) and feed them through my model the performance is terrible, with 7 out of 12 images incorrectly classified.  When I run randomly selected (by me) training or validation images (from above) through the model it works very well, which is what I would expect.  This indicates to me that the transformations I do to the input image (shrinking, transposing, converting to `numpy` array, etc) are the same and correct in all cases.

The only salient difference I can see between the video harvested images that I used for training and validation and the still images (aka snapshots) is the resolution.  The snapshots have a significantly higher resolution, although I would think that wouldn't matter given that all images are reduced to 300x300.

Any insight or ideas would be much appreciated (and probably helpful for future travelers) as I'm completely mystified as to why this isn't working.

The guts of my code:

```
model = Sequential()

filters = 32
model.add(Conv2D(filters, (3, 3), padding='same', input_shape=(image_width, image_height, 3)))

model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(filters, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(filters*2, (3, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(filters*2, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(filters*16))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(len(classes)))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=opts[opt],
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Fitting, normalization, and prediction:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        training_dir,
        target_size=(image_width, image_height),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='categorical',
        follow_links=True
)

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        validation_dir,
        target_size=(image_width, image_height),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='categorical',
        follow_links=True
)

hist = model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=train_generator.samples//batch_size,
        epochs=epochs,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=validation_generator.samples//batch_size,
        use_multiprocessing=True,
        workers=8,
        callbacks=[early_stopping, time_callback]
)

pred = model.predict_generator(validation_generator, workers=8, use_multiprocessing=True, verbose=1)
```

And the code I use to test with individual (snapshot) images:

```
#... Use with snapshots (may need to be rotated)
# image = Image.open(image_file).convert("RGB").rotate(-90).resize((width, height))

#... Use with images scraped from video (either GoPro or Android)
image = Image.open(image_file).convert("RGB").resize((width, height))

img = np.array(image)

r = img[:,:,0]
g = img[:,:,1]
b = img[:,:,2]

npimages = np.array([[r] + [g] + [b]], np.uint8)
npimages = npimages.transpose(0,2,3,1)

classes = model.predict_classes(npimages)
prediction = model.predict(npimages, verbose=2)

print(prediction)
print(classes)
print(label_map[classes[0]])

plt.imshow(img)
```

Comment: Could you provide an inference code?

Comment: Do you apply the same normalization procedure as you did with training and validation data?

Comment: Mikkola -- If I understand what you mean by 'normalization', I rescale the training/validation images by 1./255 using the Keras 'ImageDataGenerator' function.  When I do the same to the inputs to my fully trained model it fails to classify correctly every single time, both for snapshots and images used during the training or validation steps.

Comment: Marcin -- I've amended my original post to contain what I believe you mean by 'inference code'.  If it's not clear, please feel free to LMK.

Comment: I rather meant this piece of code when you run `predict` method. Of course - `fit` method might also be helpful.

Comment: Can you do some preprocessing while training and testing? You can subtract the imagenet mean for example. However, most probably the cause is that the data is correlated video frames, as noted in the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I’m afraid video data tends to be strongly correlated. That is, although a 1 minute video translates to 60 seconds of 30 fps (1800) images, most of them are very similar. It’s the same scene, "same" lighting conditions, same cars or people passing by.

If your validation image data comes from the same video sequence as your test data, you’ll get a great accuracy (nearly 100%!) but it’s similar to testing on your training data. It’s overfitting and the validation set is similar enough to the test set so the accuracy is high. Drop out might help a little, but not if your dataset is strongly correlated.

On the plus side, your coding is probably valid!

Fixes? More data is probably your best route. Even if it’s more video data taken on a different day (different cars, people, weather etc). Sorry - I know there’s a lot of work to label things. Alternatively, maybe try fine tuning a pre-trained network on your data.

Comment: Pam -- Ah, this is hugely helpful.  Yes, my validation image data comes from the same video sequences as the training (GoPro and Android).  What I may do is train on the GoPro images and validate against Android and visa-versa.

Comment: That might help a little but you might come across the same problem you’re having now. And your accuracy might be way down, too because the validation set is too different from the training data. If you can, source more data. Kaggle might have something of use. Or even more data augmentation - random clips. I would try to shuffle the frames, so instead of taking every frame, I’d only take, say, 1/30 so they’re not so correlated and have a representative spread of Android and GoPro in both training and validation data.

Comment: Thanks, all of these are helpful.  One suggestion made above that I've also heard elsewhere is to zero mean the image set.  I'm wondering how important that is since it's not straightforward with the architecture I'm using.